# I am unable to delete a tableView Row

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I have been stuck on this for some time now, I built a tableView App with the ability to delete a row. I am using with CoreData and iCloud.
When I use "editActionsForRowAt" it deletes from the view and does not reappear when I close and run the App again, the problem is as you know it is deprecated in iOS 13.

**1.)** This works great but is deprecated in iOS 13

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

// Social Sharing Button 
let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowAction.Style.default, title: "share", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
_ = "Just checking in at " + self.inspections[indexPath.row].stateID!
      })
// Delete Button
      let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowAction.Style.default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

          if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
              let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
              let inspectionsToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
              context.delete(inspectionsToDelete)
              appDelegate.saveContext()
          }
      })
     deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 237.0/255.0, green: 66.0/255.0, blue: 106.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
      shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63.0/255.0, green: 212.0/255.0, blue: 78.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
      return [deleteAction, shareAction]
  }
```

**2.)** So I ran with "trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt"
This should work but it will not swipe to delete the row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete", handler: {(action, view, success) in
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let inspectionsToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
context.delete(inspectionsToDelete)
appDelegate.saveContext()
}
})
return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

**3.)** This deletes without **1.) or 2.)** but repopulates the row when I reopen the App

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .delete {
//  delete the row from the data source
inspections.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

}
```

I must be missing something simple to get **2.)** to work any thoughts or pointing me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Drew

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {  (action, Sourceview, completionHandler) in
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let inspectionsToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
context.delete(inspectionsToDelete)
appDelegate.saveContext()
}
completionHandler(true)
}
let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
return swipeActions
}
```